# How to display two tables in one datagridview with vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, datagridview, datarelation

I will cut down my real tables to these examples:
I have two tables and they have a relation let me say ("ID" "Name_ID") and ("ID" "Name")
I would like to display table 1 with the Name instead of Name_ID.
In my case I would like to do it without a SQL join command..
I have sean something about the Datalrelation.
I have filled a dataset with my two tables and created a Datarelation as described above..

Now the last step is missing... how can I display the information ? The Column "Name_ID" does not change to the Name..

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks a lot
Florian

Comment: Add a second query that gets the rows from the Table that contains the `Name`  description, fill the ComboBox of a ComboBoxColumn, remove the TextBoxColumn that shows the `Name_ID`, bind the new ComboBoxColumn to that field setting the `DataPropertyName`. -- This if the Columns are automatically created at run-time. Otherwise, configure the DGV Columns in the Designer. The DataSource of the ComboBox must be set at run-time in any case. Unless you use the Visual Studio tools to build those queries... (you didn't define how you handle the data)

Comment: What is wrong with using a join?